# Heroku can not find gem after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I am deploying an app to Heroku, everything went smoothly, but when it came to the more exotic gems I got this error:

No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rwordnet-0.1.3/lib/wordnet/../../WordNet-3.0/dict/data.

I am using rwordnet gem. It works fine locally in production (had to require it in application.rb though).

Any suggestions?

Thanks )

And happy holidays..

EDIT: Oh yes, that is the case:

https://github.com/doches/rwordnet/issues/1

this issue is the problem. Thereby another question - how can I edit the file in /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ in Heroku?

Comment: Try building a fresh gemset `rvm gemset create wordnettest`, and do the bundle install again locally, see if you have the same problem.

Comment: After that, check what is in your `rwordnet-0.1.3/WordNet-3.0/dict/data` folder

Comment: Actually, looking at the source on github, there is no "WordNet-3.0/dict/data". https://github.com/doches/rwordnet/tree/master/WordNet-3.0/dict

Comment: Is your gem using any other external binary code?

Comment: Thanks people, I think I know what the cause is but still not sure how to deal with it, I edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually solved this,

had to unpack the gem

gem unpack rwordnet --target vendor/gems

Then edit the pos.rb file ("a" => "adj", "r=>"adv") and then add it to Gemfile

gem "rwordnet", '0.1.3', :path => "vendor/gems/rwordnet-0.1.3"

thanks to these two posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507034/861181

 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4971668/861181